# sparql wikidata identifiers reference

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I use KMDb person ID to retrieve information from wikidata database.
The result are three rows with three IMDB codes.
If I look actress wikidata webpage (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q7496795) I can see that only one of these has a reference.

How can I select only this item? Is it possible to show the reference as an output of sparql query?

Thanks a lot

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd:       <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt:      <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs:     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX p:        <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v:        <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pr: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/>

SELECT ?wikidata ?imdb ?Q ?prop ?value
       WHERE {
   ?wikidata wdt:P345  ?imdb .
   ?wikidata wdt:P31   wd:Q5 .
    ?wikidata wdt:P1649 "00003964" . # KMDb person ID
}
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[References in Wikidata](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#References) use the property `prov:wasDerivedFrom` to represent provenance information about *statements*. In your case, one way to get rid of references without value (the value node is also a statement) would be just to add a triple pattern for that:

```
SELECT ?wikidata ?imdb ?Q ?prop ?value
WHERE
{
  ?wikidata p:P345 ?statement. 
            ?statement ps:P345 ?imdb; 
                       prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref .
  ?wikidata wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?wikidata wdt:P1649 "00003964". # KMDb person ID
}
LIMIT 10
```

But you don't need to add a variable for the statement at all. As [suggested by @WikidataFacts](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fwikidata%20%3Fimdb%20%3FQ%20%3Fprop%20%3Fvalue%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20p%3A%20points%20to%20a%20statement%20node.%0A%20%20%23%20the%20statement%20node%20is%20linked%20via%20ps%3A%20to%20the%20statement%20value%2C%0A%20%20%23%20pq%3A%20to%20qualifiers%2C%20and%20has%20some%20other%20triples%20too%2C%0A%20%20%23%20e.%E2%80%AFg.%20the%20references%20via%20prov%3AwasDerivedFrom.%0A%20%20%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP345%20%5B%20ps%3AP345%20%3Fimdb%3B%20prov%3AwasDerivedFrom%20%3Fref%20%5D.%0A%20%20%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP1649%20%2200003964%22.%20%23%20KMDb%20person%20ID%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2010), it would be more efficient if the object of `p:P345` is directly the description of the blank node:

```
SELECT ?wikidata ?imdb ?Q ?prop ?value
WHERE
{
  ?wikidata p:P345 [ ps:P345 ?imdb; prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref ].
  ?wikidata wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?wikidata wdt:P1649 "00003964". # KMDb person ID
}
LIMIT 10
```

There are more options, such as using explicit blank node, or filtering only nodes which have at least one value.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, I'd be wary of depending on any reference of the form "Imported from xyz Wikipedia." It really has no more value than no reference at all. Of the three identifiers returned, one is clearly wrong and the other two are duplicates of each other at IMDb. I'm not sure there's a good way to distinguish the two case from the data alone.